# pyinstaller package gets UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte

Tags: windows-10, pyinstaller, python-3.7

I'm a new python learner, I've written a python program and run it correctly.
I use the tool, Pyinstaller, to pack the program and I get a package. But when I run it, some error occurs. Is there someone can help me?
The error message is below!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tokenize.py", line 385, in find_cookie
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb4 in position 4: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "iClean_estimation.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 71, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\traceback.py", line 193, in format_stack
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\traceback.py", line 207, in extract_stack
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\traceback.py", line 357, in extract
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\traceback.py", line 281, in line
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\linecache.py", line 16, in getline
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
  File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\linecache.py", line 136, in updatecache
  File "tokenize.py", line 449, in open
  File "tokenize.py", line 426, in detect_encoding
  File "tokenize.py", line 390, in find_cookie
SyntaxError: invalid or missing encoding declaration for 'c:\\programdata\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\loader\\pyimod03_importers.py'
[19168] Failed to execute script iClean_estimation
```

Here's a picture of the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbFgx.png
The pyinstaller command I use is as bellow:

```
pyinstaller -F -c --icon="Input\icon\iclean.ico" %name%.py
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: When posting stack traces, please include all the new-lines by copy and pasting the error as-is into a code block (like you've tried). I don't know why or how the new-lines got lost, but please add them so that the question looks like the picture - but is in a text format. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've upload the detail message ,can you help me?

Comment: You're using anaconda? Could you try this on a vanilla Python installation to eliminate certain fault parameters.

Comment: Thank you! After a week's hard trying work. I've overcome this problem.

Comment: After updating my matplotlib version , this error magicly disappear.^_^